# Confidence interval for ratio in timeseries

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, independence

I have a time series $X(t)$. Each $X(t)$ has three possible outcomes: A, B or C. I am interested in the ratio of A, B and C to the total. Assuming $N$ is the number of data points I have gathered for $X(t)$,
*How can I compute the confidence levels for A/N, B/N and C/N when the $X(t)$ are "intuitively" not independent ?*

For example, $X(t)$ is an indication of whether a car is: moving (speed>0), stopped (speed=0) or its motor is off. The data I gathered is a time slice pertaining to a car. To me, those categories are not independent because when the car is moving at $X(t)$ is very likely to be still moving at $X(t)$. [Am I correct?]

Comment: What kind of inference are you making?  E.g., do you view the discrete values X(t1), X(t2), ... as a sample from a continuous set of values about which you would like to draw conclusions, or do you view this time series as a sample from many possible such series for a particular combination of car/driver/conditions/location, or do you perhaps view it as a sample from possible time series for many cars and drivers?

Comment: @whuber: in this case, it's really a single car making measurements so my hunch is that it's not independent : am I right ? I will, at one point, be in a "crowdsourcing" case where a lot of independent cars will be driving and I will be looking at what's happening in the same spots : in that case, can I consider them independent even though they should be measuring the same thing ? I think so but I'd like to be extra sure.

Comment: "Independence" makes sense only after you have adopted a chance model for the data.  Several good models are appropriate.  Which one(s) to use depend on the decisions you plan to make.  So: it seems you wish to estimate the proportion of time spent moving, stopped, or off.  Will you use these proportions to characterize (a) the history of a single ride, (b) conditions along a route traveled by many cars at the same time, (c) a route to be traveled extensively in the future, or (d) some other generalization of the data?

Comment: @whuber: thanks for the socratic approach :) Right now, I am working on proving that a new process is equivalent to an old one (see another post I made) so (a) is what I'm interested in. Am I correct in thinking that had I been in case (b), I could consider the time series to be independent ? I'm curious to know what (c) is about ? Prediction based on my current measurements ?

Comment: This question isn't well defined and should be closed. In addition to not considering how "dependence" would (or wouldn't) affect a desired estimator, more details about the structure of the time series are required, such as whether it's discrete with no imbalance, or continuous with potentially imbalanced measurement.